# Is there a limit in the length of Magento Classes?

Tags: magento, block

I found an unexpected issue while attempting to load a block within a magento module. The block name was *Mycompany_CustomerModule_Block_CustomerModuleDashboardDataBlock* (yes, the name is very long, but I added the module name all blocks related to the module to avoid confusing a dashboard.html with the one used by Magento Core).
The issue is that, if I try to load such block, with the following command:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('customermodule/customermoduledashboarddatablock')
```

Magento raises the exception "Invalid block type". I couldn't figure out what was wrong, since I copied the whole file from a block that works perfectly, and then I tried renaming the block to something shorter, such as simply *DashboardDataBlock*. With the shorter name, block is loaded correctly.

My question is, therefore, are there any limitations in the length of Classes' names? I can always shorten the class name, but I'd like to know if there are limits so that I can avoid having similar issues in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple of things at play here. If you are on a case-sensitive filesystem, then the issue is that you need to match camelCasing between your filename and class ID (`customermoduledashboarddatablock` in your case), with the note that the first letter of any folder or file which is resoled by the autoloader will need to be uppercase regardless of class prefix or class ID. Additionally, note that PHP does not care about casing of class names and method calls - only the autoloader cares, and only on case-sensitive filesystems.

The other possible issue could be total filename length in a Windows environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about the case sensitivity issue, I had to deal with it not long ago, when I had a Model that was not loaded because both file name and class name were in CamelCase. It started working perfectly when I renamed the file, leaving only the first letter capitalized (I didn't change the CamelCase in the class name, and it worked). I tried changing the casing of class and file name, but it didn't make a difference. Good point about the filename length, I'm using Windows and I keep forgetting that the symlinks get resolved to the full original path. I'll check that.

Comment: Ok,I checked the total filename length and I'm way below the maximum supported by Windows 7 x64, it must be something else underneath. Not a big deal anymore, since I renamed the file to something I liked better, now everything works. Time to try it on the Linux server, case-sensitivity testing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, regardless of file system case-sensitivity, that the last part of Magento class name **must not** be camel cased.

- `MyNamespace_MyModule_MyClassName` **NO**
- `MyNamespace_MyModule_myclassname` **NO**
- `MyNamespace_MyModule_myclassName` **NO**
- `MyNamespace_MyModule_Myclassname` **YES**
- `MyNamespace_MyModule_My_Class_Name` **YES**

You will notice this pattern in core modules, too. Class prefixes of namespace and module are read from the configuration files and can contain arbitrary upper case letters. But the actual class names are derived from the class alias in a way that does not allow upper case letters (have a look at the code in `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassname()` if you want to know, why. *Hint:* it uses `uc_words`)